# How is multitasking possible even if it's just context switching and finish all processes simultaneously?

Tags: operating-system, multiprocessing, cpu, multitasking, context-switch

For what I have read multitasking is nothing but context switching happening at really fast speed and hence giving an illusion of parallelism.

But I am confused. Even with context switching whole data has to be processed, then how CPU achieves it at the same time?

For eg. I am listening to 5 minutes long song in VLC and listening another song of 5 minutes in KMP. So CPU has to process 10 min long data. But both songs finish at the same time. How is it possible? Please correct if I have misinterpreted some of the concepts.

Can you provide answers for both single and multicore processors?

Comment: 'Even with context switching whole data has to be processed, then how CPU achieves it at the same time?' because the processes/threads are mostly waiting for I/O, so there is enough free CPU available when the I/O is completed. Modern preemptive muultitasking kernels are all about high-performance I/O. CPU execution is withheld from threads that cannot use it because they are waiting for IO or signals from other threads and supplied to those thread that can make progress.  Having more than one core just gives more opportunity for the kernel to dispatch ready threads onto those cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that multitasking on a single CPU core is just rapid context switching.  This gets a little more complicated when you consider multi-core CPUs, but the idea is largely the same.

Audio devices are a particularly interesting example.  They have buffers for playback from which they generate the sound *on their own*, without CPU intervention.  How that works with multi-tasking is that, as the playback buffer gets low, the sound device will notify the OS (or a driver, or an application), and some CPU time will be spent filling the buffer back up.  Fortunately, transferring data into the buffer is much faster than playback, so this leaves the CPUs free for all of the other things they have to do.

There's one more system involved in your example: Somewhere in your system, a 'mixer' is implemented.  Sometimes this is on the sound-card, other times it's in the OS.  The mixer is responsible for taking the sounds that all of the applications want to play, and combining them into a single playback stream that can be fed into the sound-card's buffer.  Fortunately, mixing is also not overly complex, so it still doesn't take nearly as much time to mix 10 seconds of audio as it takes to play it back.

Comment: So I assume other tasks also have some buffer? For eg. playing a game and running some other application simultaneously. Keypresses have higher priority so it is registered instantly while controlling the game. Am I getting it right?

Comment: yes.  For example, on Windows, each window has a message queue.  Whenever a key is pressed several messages are sent to the window with 'focus'.  One message indicates the key is pressed, another indicates when the key is released, and another indicates if a character was typed.  The application that owns the window will process these messages whenever its timeslice comes around.  For reference, the timeslice for windows context switching was about 10ms (100 context switches per second) so you never notice the slight delays on key-presses.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b 'The application that owns the window will process these messages whenever its timeslice comes around' - NO!  This is, at least, very badly misleading.  If there is a core available, the app thread that handles the messages, typically the one managing the GUI, will be made running immediately the message is made available.  There is no waiting for 'timeslices'.  This high-performance I/O is the main reason for using preemptive multitasking OS like Windows.

Comment: One way to read what you've said is that the OS tries to give that thread a time-slice as soon as it can.  Sometimes this is immediately as you indicate, but sometimes it is not.  Particularly on single-core CPUs, which are included in the OP's scope.  Don't forget that under every WindowClass there is still a TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage loop that process all messages, whether they are keyboard, mouse, IPC, etc.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b 'TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage loop' - yes, but you forgot the 'GetMessage()' call at the top of the loop.  That is a blocking call that removes CPU from the GUI thread while there are no messages to process.  When a message is posted/sent, the GUI thread is ready to run.  If a core is available, (that means one that is actually free/halted OR one that the scheduling algorithm and thread state data instructs can be be preempted), then that ready GUI thread will be made running 'immediately'.

Comment: I don't think we're saying different things.